# R, dplyr: Get number of repeated cells in list of matrices

Tags: r, matrix, dplyr, tidyverse

##### EDIT

Adding an example with 4x4 matrices to test

Matrices:

```
> mat1
[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    1    0
[2,]    0    1    0    1
[3,]    1    1    1    1
[4,]    0    1    0    1
> mat2
[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    0
[2,]    1    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1    1
[4,]    0    1    0    0
> mat3
[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    0    1
[2,]    1    0    0    1
[3,]    0    0    0    1
[4,]    1    0    1    0
> mat4
[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    1    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    1    1
[4,]    0    0    1    1


sample_list <- list(mat1, mat2, mat3, mat4)
```

```
m12     <- as.matrix(sample_list[[1]] + sample_list[[2]]) 
sum_row <- rowSums(m12*(m12 > 1)) %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
           rowid_to_column(., var = "id") %>% 
           rename(., "sum_row" = ".")
num_rep <- m12 %>% 
           apply(.,1,function(x) sum(x > 1)) %>% as.data.frame()%>% 
           rowid_to_column(., var = "id") %>% 
           rename(., "num_rep" = ".")
rep2    <- full_join(sum_row, num_rep) %>%
           mutate(sum_rep2 = sum_row - num_rep) %>%
           select(., id, sum_rep2)


m123    <- as.matrix(sample_list[[1]] + sample_list[[2]] + sample_list[[3]]) 
sum_row <- rowSums(m123*(m123 > 1)) %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
           rowid_to_column(., var = "id") %>% 
           rename(., "sum_row" = ".")
num_rep <- m123 %>% 
           apply(.,1,function(x) sum(x > 1)) %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
           rowid_to_column(., var = "id") %>% 
           rename(., "num_rep" = ".")
rep3    <- full_join(sum_row, num_rep) %>%
           mutate(sum_rep3 = sum_row - num_rep) %>%
           select(., id, sum_rep3)


m1234   <- as.matrix(sample_list[[1]] + sample_list[[2]] + sample_list[[3]] + sample_list[[4]]) 
sum_row <- rowSums(m1234*(m1234 > 1)) %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
           rowid_to_column(., var = "id") %>% 
           rename(., "sum_row" = ".")
num_rep <- m1234 %>% 
           apply(.,1,function(x) sum(x > 1)) %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
           rowid_to_column(., var = "id") %>% 
           rename(., "num_rep" = ".")
rep4    <- full_join(sum_row, num_rep) %>%
           mutate(sum_rep4 = sum_row - num_rep) %>%
           select(., id, sum_rep4)


all_reps <- full_join(rep2, rep3) %>%
            full_join(., rep4)
```

The final output:

```
id sum_rep2 sum_rep3 sum_rep4
1        1        3        4
2        2        4        4
3        4        5        7
4        1        1        3
```

##### ORIGINAL POST

I have a list of adjacency matrices. I'm trying to count up the number of times a filled cell is repeated for each observation. My goal is to do this with the matrices sequentially. So, the number of repeats with M1 and M2, then M1, M2, and M3, etc.

I'm trying to create a function to do this with as many matrices as provided in the list. The code below is what I've been using to do this one step at a time.

Example matrices:

```
set.seed(0)

mat1 <- matrix(sample(0:1, 10*10, replace=TRUE),10,10) %>% 
        replace(., col(.) == row(.), 0)
mat2 <- matrix(sample(0:1, 10*10, replace=TRUE),10,10) %>% 
        replace(., col(.) == row(.), 0)
mat3 <- matrix(sample(0:1, 10*10, replace=TRUE),10,10) %>% 
        replace(., col(.) == row(.), 0)
mat4 <- matrix(sample(0:1, 10*10, replace=TRUE),10,10) %>% 
        replace(., col(.) == row(.), 0)

sample_list <- list(mat1, mat2, mat3, mat4)
```

Code I've used:

Here I calculate the sum of cells by row and the number of filled cells greater than 1. I subtract the number of cells from the total row sums to get the total number of repeats.

```
m12     <- as.matrix(sample_list[[1]] + sample_list[[2]]) 
sum_row <- rowSums(m12*(m12 > 1)) %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
           rowid_to_column(., var = "id") %>% 
           rename(., "sum_row" = ".")
num_rep <- m12 %>% 
           apply(.,1,function(x) sum(x > 1)) %>% as.data.frame()%>% 
           rowid_to_column(., var = "id") %>% 
           rename(., "num_rep" = ".")
rep2    <- full_join(sum_row, num_rep) %>%
           mutate(sum_rep2 = sum_row - num_rep) %>%
           select(., id, sum_rep2)


m123    <- as.matrix(sample_list[[1]] + sample_list[[2]] + sample_list[[3]]) 
sum_row <- rowSums(m123*(m123 > 1)) %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
           rowid_to_column(., var = "id") %>% 
           rename(., "sum_row" = ".")
num_rep <- m123 %>% 
           apply(.,1,function(x) sum(x > 1)) %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
           rowid_to_column(., var = "id") %>% 
           rename(., "num_rep" = ".")
rep3    <- full_join(sum_row, num_rep) %>%
           mutate(sum_rep3 = sum_row - num_rep) %>%
           select(., id, sum_rep3)



m1234   <- as.matrix(sample_list[[1]] + sample_list[[2]] + sample_list[[3]] + sample_list[[4]]) 
sum_row <- rowSums(m1234*(m1234 > 1)) %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
           rowid_to_column(., var = "id") %>% 
           rename(., "sum_row" = ".")
num_rep <- m1234 %>% 
           apply(.,1,function(x) sum(x > 1)) %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
           rowid_to_column(., var = "id") %>% 
           rename(., "num_rep" = ".")
rep4    <- full_join(sum_row, num_rep) %>%
           mutate(sum_rep4 = sum_row - num_rep) %>%
           select(., id, sum_rep4)


all_reps <- full_join(rep2, rep3) %>%
            full_join(., rep4)
```

The final output, `all_reps` gives me this dataset (with the random matrices I created in the first chunk of code):

```
  id sum_rep2 sum_rep3 sum_rep4
1   1        1        7       10
2   2        3        8       10
3   3        1        5       10
4   4        0        1        4
5   5        2        4        9
6   6        0        2        4
7   7        3        6       10
8   8        5        8       12
9   9        3        7       11
10 10        3        9       12
```

Is there a way to use a loop or an apply function to do this in a more automated way, that also will take a list of more matrices?

Matrices:

```
sample_list[[1]]
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0    1    0    1    1    0    0    1    1     1
 [2,]    0    0    0    1    1    1    0    1    1     0
 [3,]    1    0    0    1    1    0    1    1    1     0
 [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0     1
 [5,]    0    0    0    1    0    1    1    0    0     1
 [6,]    1    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0     0
 [7,]    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    1    1     0
 [8,]    0    1    1    1    1    1    1    0    0     0
 [9,]    0    1    0    0    1    1    0    0    0     1
[10,]    1    1    0    1    0    1    1    0    0     0

sample_list[[2]]
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    1    0     0
 [2,]    1    0    1    0    1    1    0    0    1     0
 [3,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     1
 [4,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     0
 [5,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    1    0    0     1
 [6,]    0    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0     1
 [7,]    0    1    0    0    1    1    0    1    0     1
 [8,]    0    1    0    1    1    1    1    0    1     0
 [9,]    1    0    1    1    1    1    0    1    0     1
[10,]    0    1    1    1    0    1    0    1    1     0

sample_list[[3]]
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
 [2,]    1    0    1    0    1    0    1    1    1     0
 [3,]    1    0    0    0    1    1    0    1    1     0
 [4,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     1
 [5,]    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    1    1     1
 [6,]    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1     0
 [7,]    1    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    1     1
 [8,]    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    1     1
 [9,]    0    1    0    1    1    0    0    1    0     0
[10,]    1    1    0    1    0    0    1    1    1     0

sample_list[[4]]
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     1
 [2,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1     0
 [3,]    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    0    1     0
 [4,]    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    1    0     1
 [5,]    0    0    0    1    0    1    1    1    0     1
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0     0
 [7,]    0    0    1    1    0    1    0    1    1     0
 [8,]    1    0    1    1    0    0    1    0    1     0
 [9,]    1    0    1    0    1    1    1    0    0     0
[10,]    1    0    1    1    1    0    0    0    0     0
```

Comment: Can you please add a `set.seed(0)` to the start so your output can be reproducible?

Comment: Done, also added the four matrices used in the code at the bottom just in case.

Comment: Could I suggest that this might be easier to understand and test solutions with smaller matrices? 3x3 or at most 4x4 matrices might be easier to work with and test solutions for.

Comment: @GregorThomas done! edits above original post

Comment: Thanks! Could you also describe a bit more in words about your calculation? I was hoping that when I looked at the 4x4 example it would be clear to me what you mean, but it's still not. Could you describe in words what it means that `id1` (which I assume corresponds to the first matrix?) has `sumRep2 = 1`?

Comment: I know you say *"count up the number of times a filled cell is repeated for each observation"* - *filled cell* seems clear, a cell with a 1, not a 0. I don't get the *"repeated for each observation"* part. I was thinking maybe `sum_rep2` would be the number of cells that are filled in both `mat1` and `mat2`, but that seems to be wrong.

Comment: Yes sorry for not being clear. Each id number is the row number in the matrix, corresponding to a student who can nominate other students as their friend. In mat1, or time1, id1 nominated id3 as a friend. In mat2, id1 nominates id1, id2, and id3 again. Since they repeated the id3 nomination, their sum_rep2 is 1. Verabally, it's the sum of repeated nominations minus the number of nominations in the most recent time (in this case, matrix).

Comment: Further, for sum_rep3, the sum of the first three matrices gives id1 a row sum of 7, since they nominated the first three ids twice and the last one once. Row sum of 7, minus 4, the number of nominations made, gives a sum_rep3 of 3. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this gives you what you're after:

```
library(tidyverse)

accumulate(sample_list, `+`) %>%
  tail(-1) %>%
  map(~ rowSums(pmax(.x - 1, 0))) %>%
  bind_cols(.name_repair = ~ paste0("sum_rep", seq_along(.x)+1)) %>%
  rowid_to_column()

# A tibble: 4 x 4
  rowid sum_rep2 sum_rep3 sum_rep4
  <int>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1     1        0        0        0
2     2        0        1        2
3     3        1        3        4
4     4        0        0        2
```

Sample data:

```
set.seed(0)
n <- 4
sample_list <- replicate(4, `diag<-`(matrix(sample(0:1, n*n, replace=TRUE),n), 0), simplify = FALSE)
```